# Selecting unique records from mysql with considering only one field

Tags: php, mysql, select

My question may be  not reflecting my problem, sorry for that at first. I have a problem , I need to select distinct movie names from a table also selecting its id and other records. But since ids are different for each movies, all the movies are selected(with same name ). Here's the query :

```
    $sql = "
            SELECT DISTINCT
                movie_id,movie_name
            FROM
                tbl_current_movies as cm, tbl_movie_hall as mh
            WHERE
                movie_active = 'active'
            AND
                cm.hall_id = mh.hall_id
        ";

$res = $this->db->returnArrayOfObject($sql,$pgin = 'no');

    var_dump($res);
```

And `var_dump($res)` says :

```
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[48]
      public 'movie_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'movie_name' => string 'MIB' (length=12)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[49]
      public 'movie_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'movie_name' => string 'Jetuka Pator Dare' (length=17)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[50]
      public 'movie_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'movie_name' => string 'MIB' (length=12)
```

So as you can see the movie MIB is showing twice, but I want to get in the results the movies MIB only once !

Comment: Which movie_id do you want then? 1 or 3?

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to this :

```
 $sql = "SELECT movie_id , movie_name
         FROM tbl_current_movies as cm 
         LEFT JOIN  tbl_movie_hall mh ON cm.hall_id = mh.hall_id
         WHERE movie_active = 'active'
         GROUP BY movie_name
        ";
```

You shouldn't join your tables in the WHERE clause, if you're not confortable with the JOINs you can read some of the docs : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html
That should help you understand what they are for.